# Convergence of a sequence in $l^{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> $x_n$ converges to $y=(y^1,y^2,\dotsc)$ in $l^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ if $\sup_\limits{j\in\mathbb{N}}|x_n^j-y^j|\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. Is it true that for each for each $j$, $x_n^j\to y^j$, then $x_n\to y$ in $l^{\infty}$?

Let $\epsilon>0$. Since $x_n^j\to y^j$, we have that $|x_n^j|\leq M_j$ and $|y^j|\leq M_j$. **Let us suppose $M_j$ decreases to $0$ as $j\to\infty$.** Pick $i$ large enough so that $2M_i<\epsilon$. Then for all $n$, $|x_n^i-y^i|\leq |x_n^i|+|y^i|=2M_i<\epsilon$. Then for $j\geq i$, $|x_n^j-y^j|\leq 2M_j\leq 2M_i<\epsilon$ and so $\sup\limits_{j\geq i}|x_n^j-y^j|<\epsilon$. Now let $j<i$. Since $|x_n^j-y^j|\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, $\exists K_j$ such that $n\geq K_j\implies |x_n^j-y^j|<\epsilon$. Then for $n\geq K=\max\{K_1,K_2,\dots,K_{i-1}\}$, we have $|x_n^j-y^j|<\epsilon$ for $j\in\{1,2,\dots,i-1\}$. Thus, for $n\geq K$, we have $|x_n^j-y^j|<\epsilon$ for all $j$ and so $\sup\limits_{j\in\mathbb{N}}|x_n^j-y^j|\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Question 1: Does my argument look correct?

Question 2: Is there a way to drop the assumption that the $M_j$ for a decreasing sequence converging to $0$?

Comment: To question 2- when you have the answer to that, you will have the answer to the exercise. My advice is to start thinking of stupid examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument is incorrect.

Run your argument through the special case $y_j = 0, \, x_n^j = \frac{j}{n+j}$ to see where the error is.

Answer (score 0):

Consider members of $l^{\infty}$ as functions from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb R.$ The topology of $l^{\infty}$ is the topology of uniform convergence: A sequence $(f_m)_{m\in \mathbb N}$ of members of $l^{\infty}$ converges to $f \in l^{\infty}$ iff if the sequence converges uniformly, as a sequence of functions. Point-wise convergence is insufficient to imply uniform convergence. For example let $f_m(m)=1,$ and $f_m(n)=0$ when $n\ne m.$  Then $(f_m)_m$ converges point-wise to $0$ but $\|f_m\|=1$ for every $m.$